# Angular Material Dropdown with Router ( UI - Router )

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drop-down-menu, angular-ui-router, angular-material

when user clicks on the person it calls a form (form.html) using ui-router logic defined in app.js. I have 2 type of drop-down boxes, (1) using select tag and (2) using md-select tag. Pages works fine until i click on 2nd dropdown, which doesn't open the dropdown option window instead it freezes the page. I added code here in plunker however page routing doesn't work in plunker but you can reference the code.

index.html

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
            <div class="col-sm-3 sidenav">
                <div class="well"> <!-- container to hold status bar and form -->
                    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-custom">
                        <a style="font-size:2.5em;position: absolute; left: 50%;" ui-sref="form"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user fa-5x" id="Icon"></span></a>
                    </nav>

                    <div class="column-nav-form" ui-view="formColumn" >  <!--holds the form -->
                    </div>
                </div> 
            </div>
    </body>
```

form.html

```
<body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <h4> Normal DropDown </h4>
    <select ng-model="selectedName" ng-options="x for x in names">
    </select>
</div>
<p>I have three elements in my list, you should be able to pick whichever you like</p>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <h4> Material DropDown </h4>
    <md-select onclick='console.log("clicked")' ng-model="selectedFilter" placeholder="Select a filter">                             <md-select-label>{{ selectedFilter.name }}</md-select-label> 
        <md-option ng-value="opt" ng-repeat="opt in filters">{{ opt.name }}</md-option>
    </md-select>
</div>
</body>
```

app.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [ 'ngAnimate', 'ngAria', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'ui.router' ]);

//routing
angular.module('myApp').config(function ($stateProvider){

    $stateProvider
        .state('form', {
        url:"/form",
            views:  {
                "listColumn": {

                  },
                "formColumn": {
                      templateUrl: "/form.html"
                  } 
            }
        })  
});

//dropdown
myApp.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    //log
    console.log($scope.names);
    $scope.names = ["Emil", "Tobias", "Linus"];

    $scope.filters = [
            {
                value: 'mine',
                name: 'Assigned to me'
            },
            {
                value: 'undefined',
                name: 'Unassigned'
            },
            {
                value: 'all',
                name: 'All Tickets'
            },
            {
                value: 'new',
                name: 'New Tickets'
            }
        ];

    //log
    console.log($scope.filters);
    console.log($scope.selectedFilter);
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/SB7MUM44Ly01aWyL5M28?p=preview

View upon clicking person icon

[image]
Note: Dropdown for md-select doesn't load.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Instead of using `ng-value` use `value` attaribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed .css and .js version to have the same and it fixed it.

angular-material.js ( v 1.0.6 )
angular-material.css ( v 1.0.6 )

Links:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/angular/bower-material/master/angular-material.css">
<script src="https://rawgit.com/angular/bower-material/master/angular-material.js"></script>-->
```